# Unable to query on chaincode example 2

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to setup the blockchain as described on the official documents.
[Officail document link](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#running-the-chaincode)

Deploy and Invoke for blockchain seems to work fine. But whenever I perform query it fails and blockchain stops displaying the below error.

> Error starting Simple chaincode: Error handling message: [1e85621d-4ea5-4f7c-85bd-d532370416bb]Chaincode handler FSM cannot handle message (RANGE_QUERY_STATE) with payload size (10) while in state: ready

While debugging I came accross this issue https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/905 but it isnt helping.

Have someone else faced similar issue before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well got the issue. I was using docker images for deploying the peer and memberservice while fetching the latest chain code from git on my local machine in order to build and deploy. So the code which was in docker image and the latest chain code had different version hence there were some conflicts giving that error. Solved it by deploying the chaincode which was present inside the dockerimage.